# Reduce padding between border and text in Flutter DropDownMenu

Tags: flutter

I want to reduce space/padding between text and border, the yellow marked in picture

[image]

I tried the code below but its not working

```
DropdownMenu<String>(
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
        ),
        initialSelection: list.first,
        onSelected: (String? value) {
          // This is called when the user selects an item.
          setState(() {
            buttonClickedTimes.value = value!;
          });
        },
        dropdownMenuEntries:
            list.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(value: value, label: value);
        }).toList(),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired result by coding like below:

```
DropdownMenu<String>(
        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        trailingIcon: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              size: 15,
            )),
        inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: 30,
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
        ),
        initialSelection: list.first,
        onSelected: (String? value) {
          // This is called when the user selects an item.
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = value!;
          });
        },
        dropdownMenuEntries:
            list.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
            value: value,
            label: value,
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
```

BoxConstraints did the actual magic. Below is how it looks:

[image]